# How to update Play.configuration programmatically in Play 2.0?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play 1, I could write a class that extends PlayPlugin and do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationRead() {
  Play.configuration.put("logger.application","DEBUG");
}
```

I don't see how to do the equivalent in Play 2.  The Plugin interface no longer has the "on ConfigurationRead" method.  I'm not sure if it's safe to do this in onApplicationStart, and even if it was, I'm not seeing how to modify the Play.configuration object in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeking for seems now to be located in `GlobalSettings`, here is the [wiki page](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaGlobal)

Extending it, you'll be able to change the configuration or whatever global settings you want to override (Bad Requests redirect or message for instance.)